# TCP Server Response

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, recv

I'm writing a TCP python script that will act as a client and retrieve a temperature reading from a LakeShore336 Temperature Controller (which is acting as the server). I need to pass a command to the server from the client and output the response. I get outputs up to 'Spot 2' after the command is sent but when s.recv is called I'm left hanging. (Python 2.7)

Client.py

```
import socket

ip = '192.168.62.233'
port = 7777              # The same port as used by the server/machine
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((ip, port))

print 'Spot 1'
s.send('KRDG? A[term]')
print 'Spot 2'
data = s.recv(4096)
print 'Spot 3'
s.close()
print 'Received', repr(data)
```

EDIT:
In the end I just needed to add

```
s.send('KRDG? A\r\n')
```

So that there was a terminator. Thanks for the help

Comment: Correct, `recv()` is a blocking call.  It will block until the server sends a response up to 4096 bytes or closes the connection (well it is more complex than that but that's the simple story).  I bet you're not closing the connection on the server after sending the response.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code is "stuck" is because recv() is a blocking call. Your process is waiting for an inbound TCP packet and you've allocated a buffer of 4096 bytes (which means it can handle up to that amount of bytes).

Once that packet is received your code will proceed and the connection will be closed then print out the data.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the literal string `[term]` instead of sending a message terminator. The protocol documentation uses the string "[term]" to mean a message terminator, it does not mean the literal string "[term]"!

Since you have not sent a message (because a message ends with a message terminator so anything that doesn't end with a message terminator is not a message), the device will not reply with a message. Since you wait for a reply, you will wait forever.

See section 6.3.4.1 of the [protocol specification](http://www.lakeshore.com/Documents/336_Manual.pdf) for the list of supported message terminators. A carriage return followed by a newline should work.

You receive code is also broken. You are calling the TCP `recv` function and expecting it to receive a message. But it has no idea what a message is since it's just a TCP function and has no idea what message protocol you are using to communicate with this device. You have to write your own receive function to receive a message, just as you had to make sure your send code actually sent a message.

Since this device's message protocol corresponds perfectly with the common notion of a line, using functions that send and receive lines will make your life much simpler. Just use a "send line" function and tell it to send "KRDG? A". Then use a "receive line" function to get the device's response.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean about [term] I have switched that to 

s.send('KRDG? ACR 0DHALF 0AH') 

to include the terminator. Don't I already have a send line function and receive line function that should accomplish this? Or do I need to write these explicitly and remove recv()

Comment: @ScottMacdonald It's up to you. One way is to call `makefile()` on the socket, to give you an object you can call `readline` on.